# Cannot directly grab and move a vertex with the G + mouse

Tags: interface, vertices, transforms, mouse

I'm really new to Blender (v2.93.6 on ARM Mac) so I'm following tutorials on YouTube.

I'm trying to move a selected vortex with Grab + Mouse movement but this opens a little menu (called Move) in order to indirectly move the selected vortex (X, Y, Z values).

You can see the menu on the bellow picture.

[image: the menu and the selected vortex]

This is really uncomfortable to use and I am looking to use the mouse to move the vertex (like the tutorial does). What do I miss ? Thx for the help. I have searched for answers on the web but not result.

Thank you a lot for the help

Comment: Are you clicking after pressing G key? You should press G key, then move and only then click to confirm movement.

Comment: As @MarkusvonBroady says, this menu usually appears after using the _Move_ tool, i.e. after confirming with left-click or pressing Return. Of course this is uncomfortable when you expect to move it manually. This is only useful if you want to move a vertex a specified distance or if you moved it manually (then the values of your movement appear in the fields) and want to let's say round them up.

Comment: Thank you ! Indeed, I was pressing G then clicking while dragging... When I'm pressing G then moving the mouse, the vertex do not/ cannot move. However, if I press G twice then move the mouse, then the vertex is moving according to one degree of freedom which are the selected vertex edge lines. What am I doing wrong ? Thank a lot, again.

Comment: Select a vertex by clicking on it (and releasing the mouse button), now wress G key, then release it. Now move your mouse. If that doesn't work, something is wrong - a bug, or weird settings, or something weird in the .blend file...

Comment: Something is wrong, I should try to reinstall Blender in order to avoid weird settings. For exemple. Or maybe run an other version through a virtual machine. I will update the post if I find any solution to this issue.

Comment: I did not found the issue but I now know it comes from the project file. I reinstalled Blender and the issue remained. Then, I created a new project and I can now move the vertex normally. Thank you again.

Comment: I turn of Proportional Edit mode and it work for me.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp5jU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp5jU.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. Selecting a single vertex on the donut, moving with <kbd>G</kbd> didn't work.

If you had zoomed out, you would have seen the following: The mesh snaps to the grid at regular intervals.

You can turn off snap-to-grid with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or the little magnet button on top of viewport).